# Selection sort of object arrays gone wrong (Code included)?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-input

A lot of people helped me with this problem, however I am still running into sorting errors...

```
 public static String sorting(){
for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length; i++){
  for (int k = i + 1; k <pigArray.length; k++){

if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
   String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
   pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
   pigrray[k].setName(temp);
}
elseif(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())> 0){
    String temp = pigArray[k].getName();
    pigArray[k].setName( pigArray[i].getName );
    pigrray[i].setName(temp);
}
else
    pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[i].getName );`

String sorted = "";

for (int m = 0; m < pigArray.length; m++){

    sorted = sorted + "\n" + pigArray[m].getSortedName();     
}

return sorted;
}

private String name;

public void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
}

public String getSortedName() {
return name;
 }
```

pigArray is my object array storing pig names. I (with other people's help on here, I appreciate it) have been working on this for quite some time. And the output is still not quite right:

input: b, d, c

output: c, c, d

To me it looks like a part of the code above is wrong and replacing the 1st in order with second in order. I tried different ways of looping but with no success. I can assure you that my pigArray is storing the names correctly. pigArray[k].getName() is how i call the name stored in the object array.

Also no arraylist please.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a broken bubble-sort to me.  When you have a spare moment please explain what `pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[i].getName );` is supposed to achieve.

Comment: Ah i asked this sort of question earlier. If you look at my profile, someone recommended me to write it that way

Comment: [The blind leading the blind](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/67150.html). All I can say.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
   String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
   pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
   pigrray[k].setName(temp);
}
else if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())> 0){
    String temp = pigArray[k].getName();
    pigArray[k].setName( pigArray[i].getName );
    pigrray[i].setName(temp);
}
```

you have swap the name of pigArray[k] and pigArray[i] if the are different.
try return else segement, like

```
if(pigArray[k].getName().trim().compareTo(pigArray[i].getName().trim())< 0){
   String temp = pigArray[i].getName();
   pigArray[i].setName( pigArray[k].getName );
   pigrray[k].setName(temp);
}
```

Comment: I tried and the problem is still there. Thanks for your input though.